# How to make fixed header in full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

How can I make a fixed header in full Calendar.

Please look at the fiddle, Sun, mon,Tue,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat is my header.
I want this sunday to saturday header has to be fixed. If I scroll vertically, the header should not hide.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('hover', '.fc-day-number', function(){
  $('#cal-info').addClass('hide');
 var data = $(this).html();
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  $('#cal-info').css('left', offset.left);
  $('#cal-info').css('top', (offset.top - 40));
  $('#cal-info').html('information about: '+$(this).html()+'<br>Link to google: <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>');
 //p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
  $('#cal-info').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.tag{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:3px;
  max-height:60px;
  overflow: visible;  
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
}
.tag:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 16px solid red;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div style="border:solid 2px red;">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
<div class="tag hide" id="cal-info">

</div>
```

Comment: was any of the answers below helpful ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this -

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/5/)

You need to add a class on your header

```
 .fc-border-separate thead.sticky{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:table;
    background: #fff;
}
```

And add and remove on window scroll using jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('.fc-border-separate thead').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('.fc-border-separate thead').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

I hope It will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fc-widget-header {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0; 
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: `position:sticky` isnt yet supported by a majority of the relevant browsers. See http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Asticky.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.

Comment: Reason why i used position: sticky was problem with vertical scroll on my FullCalendar, solutions with position:fixed didn't work - FullCalendar make resize of columns, vertical scroll didn't work with FullCalendar header

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style.

```
.calendar {
  position:relative;
}

.fc-header {
  position:fixed;
}

.fc-content {
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see here : **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/7/)**

code :

```
var headerHeight = $(".fc-header").height()


$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight){
      $("thead").addClass("fixed")

   }else{
      $("thead").removeClass("fixed")
   }
});
```

CSS :

```
thead.fixed { position:fixed;width:100%;top:0;display:table;}
```

added a JQ where you calculate the height of the `.fc-header` and so, only after you scroll past that height, the `thead` will become fixed.

for the `thead` to become `fixed` i added a class `fixed` in the JQ and then in CSS styled that class

let me know if it helps

EDIT : **interesting downvote. hmm**

Answer (score 0):

hi here is updated fiddle.
check updated CSS at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/v98sb2a0/3/

```
.fc-border-separate thead tr
{
position: fixed;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
}
.fc-border-separate thead tr th
{
  width:80px;
}
.fc-border-separate th.fc-last, .fc-border-separate td.fc-last
{
  border-right-width: 0px;
}
```